# I am using jdbc Bolt library for conecting to neo4j database. my code running perfectly through main method but not running on servlet (tomcat)

Tags: java, jdbc, neo4j

I am using the jdbc bolt library for connecting to a Neo4J database in Java. My code runs perfectly in main method, but after I switch it to servlet it gives error `No suitable driver found for 'jdbc:neo4j:bolt://localhost'`. What should I do?

```
//Test class

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Test {
    public void test() {
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j:bolt://localhost", "neo4j", "neo4j");
            String query = "MATCH (n) return id(n)";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("RESULT: " + rs.getObject("id(n)"));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


//Servlet

import java.io.IOException;
   import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/testingservlet")
public class testingservlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public testingservlet() {
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            new Test().test();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where did you place the JDBC driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use official java [library](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/neo4j/driver/neo4j-java-driver/1.7.2/neo4j-java-driver-1.7.2.jar) for neo4j database connectivity.

Comment: Exactly how does that solve the problem of the question?